# Prevent android word prediction in html form

Tags: javascript, android, html

I made login form in jqModal box. Everything works well but if i open that form in android (4.0.3 samsung galaxy tab2) native browser and when i try put login into login field browser opens keyboard with word prediction. Effect is that i can put only first letter and space from predicted word.
My question is how to disable keyboard with world prediction and use standard browser keyboard.

```
...
<a href="#" class="gotologin" title="login">Login</a>
...
<div class="jqmWindowLogin jqmID2" id="login_modal" style="display: none;">
    <div class="jqmContent">
        <div id="log_reg">
            <form action="<some action here>" method="post" id="login_form">
                <label for="login">login/email:</label>
                <input type="text" name="input_field_login" id="login" class="text" />
                <label for="pswd">password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="input_field_pass" id="pswd" class="text"/>
                <input type="submit" value="go" id="Image1"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
...

$('#login_modal').jqmShow();
$.fn.jqmShow=function(t){return this.each(function(){t=t||window.event;$.jqm.open(this._jqm,t);});};
//jqModal version 1.4
```

I Find out that when change jqmOverlay position from fixed to absolute on simple site (wchich contains only link and login modal box) input methods works fine but still appear wrong on cms page.

Comment: Can you provide some code of your solution?

Comment: There's no "standard browser keyboard". – Android apps can tell the keyboard to not use the prediction bar, but it's up to the keyboard itself if it wants to listen. HTML does not have this attribute. – HTML has: `autocomplete` disables it completing a predicted word, `autocorrect` disables spelling correction, `autocapitalize` disables automatic uppercase, `spellcheck` disables underlining incorrect words. But none of these will disable the prediction bar, and a keyboard can also choose to ignore any of these values.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the attribute `autocomplete=false` on the input?

```
<input type="text" name="input_field_login" id="login" class="text" autocomplete="false" />
```

Comment: it should be `autocomplete="off"` and I don't think it will prevent word suggestion/prediction. It'll just turn off autocomplete.